# Checked radio button is showing as checked in RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-radiobutton

I'm using multiple RadioGroup and on page load based on service response I'm setting checked one radio button from each RadioGroup, but its not showing as checked. plz help

Comment: Are you using xml for setting checked property? `android:checked="true"` or do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: nobody can help you like that, you to describe the issue better and add code

Comment: @isthemartin I want to do it programmatically

Comment: Did you try this? `radiobutton.setChecked(true);` inside of  `onCreate` method